# rails scaffold customization path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what are all the paths that I can put modification code in to change the behavior of scaffolding? The reason I asked because I am confused when I am reading the rails guide about generators. To modify helper, you put them in lib/templates/rails/helper, and to modify any views, you put them in lib/templates/erb/. That is so random, why doesn't 'erb' need to behind 'rails' but 'helper' has to. But anyway, I just need all the paths.